# Using the 2.82 .blend on 2.83 causes problems in viewport render view

Tags: rendering

[image: Viewport]

For some reason when I switch to render view in 2.83 I have the problem shown in the image: material view mode shows all the materials in place as expected, but when I checked the hdri and environment node, but it just shows these weird colors :\

Any help is much much appreciated

Comment: Could you check if all of the shaders are still on the objects. Also if this happens when it is rendered?

Comment: Is there an Invert node involved?